Nest JS Swagger - additional properties in array of objects with dynamic fields
I need to generate swagger that will look like this:
...
components:
  schemas:
    Document:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: string
      additionalProperties:
        type: string
      required:
        - id

= basically I want an object with dynamic fields but the ID is the only required field.
I have this class:
export class Document {
  @ApiProperty()
  id!: string;

  [s: string]: string | number | boolean;
}

And I'm using the class in array only:
  @ApiBody({ type: [Document] })
  async saveDocuments(@Body() documents: Document[]) {...}

I can't find the place where to put additionalProperties. If I put it on @ApiBody it's generating invalid swagger file.
Is there a way to specify it correctly?
